# User interface for adding an item

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite, preferenceactivity

I'm building an application that will persist multiple items. I decided to save the items into a SQLite table, because it seemed like the best choice for multiple items with the same properties.

Then I needed to create a user interface for adding an item. The user needs to be able to input the values for properties before creating the item. My first choice was PreferenceActivity with a confirmation button — a menu item in the toolbar. I learned, however, that PreferenceActivity only works with SharedPreferences, not with SQLite, and that it wants to save all preferences automatically without waiting until the confirmation button is pressed.

What should I use for the user interface for adding an item? Or should I indeed use PreferenceActivity, but use SharedPreferences XML files instead of SQLite?

Comment: create your own interface on an empty activity

Comment: I want to use widgets like EditTextPreference.

Comment: So, create a view like the EditTextPreference. You can even create aview and inflate it on a dialog to create a dialog similar to EditTextPreference Dialog.